# How to execute actions without deleting the previous ones in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

every time I try to execute a new action I get an error. I guess it's because some of the previuos actions can't be executed twice, but in the tutorial I'm watching, the guy can do it without problems. How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the error you are referring to is the 'Table...already exists', it looks like you may want to start your script with:

```
drop database if exists ContactMe;
```

That will remove all tables and data in that database.

"action" is some concept invented by the UI you are using, by the way, not something that has any specific meaning in mysql.